# Returning a string value from a Typescript promise

Tags: typescript

OK, here should be some simple Typescript code. In my mind anyway...

```
public showDialog(theNickname: string): string {          
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Q/GetUserDetails',
            data: { nickname: theNickname }
        }
        this.$http(req).then((response) => {

            var c = "Nickname: " + response.data.Nickname + "<br/>";
            c = c + "Score: " + response.data.Score + "<br/>";
            c = c + "Followers: " + response.data.Followers + "<br/>";              
            return c;               

        });

    }
```

Of course, it is not returning the string value as it is being returned as a promise. I don't want to use a timeout function. How can I return the string value? It is being called from an Angular function on the html. If I change

```
public showDialog(theNickname: string): string {
```

to

```
public showDialog(theNickname: string): any {
```

it still doesn't work. I am using this code in a UI.Bootstrap Popover.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Paleo answer is correct, but you could be even awesomer and use Async/Await:

```
async function showDialog(theNickname: string): Promise<string> {          
        const req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Q/GetUserDetails',
            data: { nickname: theNickname }
        }
        const response = await this.$http(req);
        return `Nickname: ${response.data.Nickname
            }<br/>Score: ${response.data.Score
            }<br/>Followers: ${response.data.Followers}<br/>`;
}   

async function caller() {
    const message = await showDialog("TEST");
    alert(message);  
}
```

Check it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=async%20function%20showDialog(theNickname%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20req%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method%3A%20'POST'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20'%2FQ%2FGetUserDetails'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20nickname%3A%20theNickname%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20response%20%3D%20await%20this.%24http(req)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60Nickname%3A%20%24%7Bresponse.data.Nickname%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3Cbr%2F%3EScore%3A%20%24%7Bresponse.data.Score%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3Cbr%2F%3EFollowers%3A%20%24%7Bresponse.data.Followers%7D%3Cbr%2F%3E%60%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20caller()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20message%20%3D%20await%20showDialog(%22TEST%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(message)%3B%20%20%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Do you use `async` / `await` in production for a frontend application? The compiled code (using promises) seems complicated...

Comment: It may seem complicated @paleo, but it's mathematically proven to work. I use it in prod with no issues.